# PHP Module for Apache on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

Using the basic Amazon 64 Bit AMI

and I do

```
sudo yum install php
sudo yum install httpd
```

However apache is not handling php files. When I visit one it just prints the source code to the browser. There is no php module in httpd.conf. How do I fix this? i.e. is there a different package to install or how do i modify httpd.conf to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the php rpm install mod_php as well, or just the language's CLI version? Installing PHP **before** apache was install may not install/configure mod_php, since there was not Apache version available to be configured in the first place.

Comment: from this -->http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/200410.mbox/%3C000d01c4bcfa$14d70be0$ce0aa8c0@test.com%3E it seems like it installs mod_php

Comment: @Marc B - Yes you have to install httpd first or you'll need to configure the apache config file to add mod_php.